# Autowire spring data with quartz

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I'm work on spring project using jparepository and quartz scheduler,I use the following configuration class to autowire spring data with quartz ,this configuration class works well and fire job once I run project with no errors,But I want to fire jobs manually by the following spring controller but I got @autowire error with spring data

Quartz Job

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class JobOne implements Job{

@Autowired
TestrecordRepository testrecordRepository;
@Autowired
ScoreRepository scoreRepository;


public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("Job one!"); 
            List<Testrecord> records=testrecordRepository.findAll();
            for(Testrecord t:records){
                Testrecord testrecord = new Testrecord();
                testrecord.setValue_integer(t.getValue_integer());
                testrecord.setId(t.getId());
                RuleExecutor ruleExecutor = new RuleExecutor();
                Score score= ruleExecutor.processRules(testrecord);
                scoreRepository.save(score);    
            }

        }
     }
```

configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Bean
public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzSchedulerjobOne() {
    SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

    quartzScheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);

    AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
    jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

    Trigger[] triggers = {
            processjobOneTrigger().getObject()
    };

    quartzScheduler.setTriggers(triggers);

    return quartzScheduler;
}

@Bean
public JobDetailFactoryBean processjobOne() {
    JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(JobOne.class);
    jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
    return jobDetailFactory;
}

@Bean
public CronTriggerFactoryBean processjobOneTrigger() {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(processjobOne().getObject());
    cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * * * ?");
    return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
}
```

Spring controller

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            QuartzConfig.class);
    Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler)context.getBean("quartzSchedulerjobOne");

}
```

eclipse console

```
       org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:134) ~[quartz-2.1.5.jar:na]
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:387) [quartz-2.1.5.jar:na]

       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.innvo.quartz.JobOne': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository com.innvo.quartz.JobOne.testrecordRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at com.innvo.quartz.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 2 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository com.innvo.quartz.JobOne.testrecordRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 6 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted
   [ERROR] org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'DEFAULT.processJobTwo'
  org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:134) ~[quartz-2.1.5.jar:na]
at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:387) [quartz-2.1.5.jar:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.innvo.quartz.JobTwo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository com.innvo.quartz.JobTwo.testrecordRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at com.innvo.quartz.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 2 common frames omitted
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository com.innvo.quartz.JobTwo.testrecordRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 6 common frames omitted
  Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Seems you miss the annotation for this class `TestrecordRepository`

Comment: No I added it to job class  @Autowired
TestrecordRepository testrecordRepository;

Comment: Where you defined the bean name `TestrecordRepository`

Comment: TestrecordRepository is jpa repository interface.       public interface TestrecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Testrecord, Long> { }